# How do i check if the data exists in the for loop

Tags: bash, scripts

I have an array contains a series of numbers:

```
10213
20223
30843
50981
60934
```

What can I do to check if the array has an element that starts with the number 4?

```
for element in array; do
    if # $element starts with 4
    then
        echo "The data exists"
    else
        echo "No data"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. I think you mean that you want to check if any elements of the array start with `4`, is that what you mean? Or do you want to see if you have any files starting with the 4th element of the array? What would the result be in your example?

Comment: Writing the script would be easy.  But you couldn't test or verity the script with your list because **none of the number in your list starts with the number 4**.  You'd have to have a list that includes the criteria you want to filter so that you can actually see the script in a tested run.

Comment: voting to close as unclear until OP explains what they really want and show proper examples

Comment: @terdon yes sir that's what i meant. i want to check if the array has an element that starts with number 4. So based on my example, the program must echo, "No data" since there is no element that starts with #4. 

Thank you for the help and sorry for my english. im not used to speak in english :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the numbers are already in a bash array, you can do:

```bash
msg="There are no numbers starting with '4' in the array."
for num in "${array[@]}"; do
        if [[ $num =~ ^4 ]]; then
                msg="The array contains an element starting with 4"
                break
        fi
done
echo "$msg"
```

Or, if you like shorter, more cryptic solutions:

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | grep -q ^4 && echo "Yes" || echo "No"
```

Comment: Also works: `[[ $num == 4* ]]`

Comment: Also also works: `[[ ${num::1} == 4 ]]`